# How I see the Full ListView in my Android Application

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I write for testing a Android Application with a ListView. This ListView I fill with a ListAdapter and it works fine. Only if I start the Application I don't see the Full ListView :(

[image]

Here is my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package de.linde.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List valueList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            valueList.add("value" + i); 
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valueList); 

        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }

}
```

What I make wrong :(?

Comment: try by adding code in  last lv..setCacheColorHint(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your text color.

try to change text color or background color of listviwe.

it will work sure.

```
  <ListView
   android:background="#C0C0C0" <------
   android:id="@+id/listview1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>
```

Comment: how are the Attributes for this?